# Are the graphs $C_{2n}^{n-1}$ strongly regular?

Tags: graph-theory

> Are the graphs $C_{2n}^{n-1}$ strongly regular?  If they are, are there any other strongly regular graphs with parameters $$(v,k, \lambda, \mu)=(v,v-2,v-4,v-2)\,?$$

Here $C_k$  is the cycle with $k$ vertices, and $G^k$ is the graph with vertex set $V(G)$, where any two vertices $u$ and $v$ are adjacent if the distance between $u$ and $v$ in $G$ is at most $k$. A regular graph $G$ of degree $k$ with $v$ vertices, is said to be *strongly regular*, denoted by $\text{srg}(v, k, \lambda, \mu)$, if any two adjacent vertices in $G$ have $\lambda$ common neighbors and any two non adjacent vertices in $G$ have $\mu$ common neighbors.

Comment: This question needs much more context. What is $C_{2n}^{n-1}$? My guess is that $C_{2n}$ is a cycle, and the exponent $n-1$ is a product of some kind. But there are many notions of graph product. The notion of a regular graph has one obvious parameter: the degree of a vertex. So what do all of these other parameters signify? Maybe $v$ is number of vertices, $k$ is degree of regularity? This question needs much more context.

Comment: $C_{k}$ is the cycle with $k$ vertices. $G^k$ is the graph with vertex set $V(G)$, where any two vertices $u$ and $v$ are adjacent if the distance between $u$ and $v$ in $G$ is at most $k$. Yes $v$ is the number of vertices. A regular graph $G$ of degree $k$ is said to be strongly regular if any two adjacent vertices in $G$ have $\lambda$ common neighbors and any two non adjacent vertices in $G$ have $\mu$ common neighbors.

Comment: Thanks these details will make the question much more likely to attract answers. However, they should be in the body of the question itself (not comments). There is an "edit" feature you can use to edit the question.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I am new here!!

Comment: Thank you @Batominovski for editing and making it look more neat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps a lot if you look at what is $C_{2n}^{n-1}$ : In an even cycle any two vertices are at distance at most $n-1$, except for "opposite vertices" in the cycle which are at distance n.

We get that $C_{2n}^{n-1}$ is just the complete graph $K_{2n}$ minus a perfect matching. For example, for $n=4$, we get $C_8^3=K_8\setminus\{\text{red edges}\}$ :

[image]

From there it is easy to derive that it is indeed $srg(v,v-2,v_4,v-2)$

- it is $v-2$ regular,
- any two no adjacent vertices are opposite and have the same
  neighbourhood, hence $\mu=v-2$,
- any two adjacent vertices do not have there respective opposite vertices as common neighbour so that $\lambda=v-4$.

Now for the second part of the question : no these are the only ones. it can be done by construction. Start with a set of $v=2n$ vertices $\{u_1,\ldots,u_v\}$ and no edges so far. Because $v_1$ has degree $v-2$ it is incident with all other vertices except one, call this one $v_{n+1}$. Because $\mu=v-2=d(v_{n+1})$, $v_1$ and $v_{n+1}$ are connected to all other vertices. Repeat for $(v_2,v_{n+2})$ and so on. We must end up with $C_{2n}^{n-1}$.

Comment: Thank for that illuminating answer including a beautiful figure.

Comment: Happy to help! After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thank you Sir, I really didn't know that!!